# Capybara Poltergeist doesn't execute javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

i am writing a Rails 3 application where a piece of code tries to navigate through a website using Capybara Poltergeist.
The body of the website has a frame:

```
    <frame src = "Nsis/html/Splash.jsp" name="ApplicationFrame" scrolling="yes" noresize>
```

Inside this frame i have an element:

```
<span class=\"SpanApplicationLink\" title=\"XML\" tabindex=\"10\" onmouseout=\"javascript: changeColorFont(this,2);\" onmouseover=\"javascript: changeColorFont(this,1);\" onclick=\"javascript:goLink('C','gesxml');\" style=\"color: rgb(0, 153, 204); \">XML</span>
```

that i want to click. 
When clicked, the element should update the frame with a new content but in my application the related javascript function is not executed and the frame continues to contain the same body.
I tried to call the function in 3 ways:

- `page.within_frame("ApplicationFrame") do page.find(:xpath,"//span[text()='XML']").click end`
  that returns {"x"=>274, "y"=>289} but without "status"=>"success"
- `page.within_frame("ApplicationFrame") do page.execute_script("javascript:goLink('C','gesxml');") end`
  that raises Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError
- `page.within_frame("ApplicationFrame") do page.execute_script("parent.ApplicationFrame.document.body.querySelector('span[title=\"XML\"]').click();") end`
  that raises Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError

How can i do to trigger this event ? I am stuck on this problem and can't find where the issue is :/

My system configuration is:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ruby 1.9.3p484
- Rails 3.2.6
- phantomjs 1.9.8
- capybara (2.4.4)
- poltergeist (1.5.1)